# Use strict passed the non declared variable?

Tags: javascript, strict

Wonder what's happening behind the scenes for the below snippet or -https://jsfiddle.net/uhznvphn/
When the global x=20 is commented out, it errors out which is fine!
But when it is uncommented, it prints 10. Shouldn't it error out because we are still in strict mode and local "x" variable has has not been declared. Even if it did not error out, shouldn't it print 20

```
x = 20; //Comment and uncomment to see diff results
function a() {
"use strict";
x = 10;
console.log(x);
}

a();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `x` variable has been declared, on line 1. It has been declared implicitly (without a `var`), but that doesn't matter because strict mode wasn't engaged at the time it was declared.

It shouldn't print `20` because a new value has been written to it before the value was logged.